# Unity Ads and IAP not working after Apple reviews the app

Tags: unity-game-engine, app-store, xcode8, unityads

I've had this problem for a couple weeks now, and I can't seem to find the fix.

I'm using Unity 5.5.1. The app I've created contains ads and IAP, but neither work whenever I upload the game to the App Store, and download it from there. (After Apple reviews it and I publish it)

To my surprise, however, the ads work whenever I upload the game to the iPhone directly, through Xcode. (The fact that IAP doesn't is common)

Below are my Xcode settings. I do not get any errors throughout the uploading and review processes, so I am completely lost right now.

PS. Similar build works perfectly on Play Store.

[Capabilities]

[image: Capabilities]

[ifconfig]

[image: ifconfig]

Comment: Hi! How you fixed? Same issue

Comment: I did not, haha